# Stuck in making 2D game movement engine

Tags: 2d

I am making a movement engine for my top-down 2D game, but I got stuck trying to solve the following problem:

- The player can move using the arrow keys, which accelerate you in the respective directions. There is friction so you stop moving after releasing the keys, though not instantly.
- When you hold two perpendicular keys, you accelerate in this 45° direction the same speed as you would on one axis
- There is a maximum speed which above you cannot accelerate **by walking**, this also limits your maximum walking speed, obviously. You can get knocked away, and thus exceed this speed however.
- If you move faster than max. walkspeed, you can slow down faster if you hold keys in the opposite direction(s)

Pseudocode for the first point, without friction:

```
gameTick(){

  tempX += LeftKeyHeld ? -1 : 0;
  tempX += RightKeyHeld ? 1 : 0;
  tempY += UpKeyHeld ? -1 : 0;
  tempY += DownKeyHeld ? 1 : 0;
  ratio = 0.71;

  if( |tempX| == |tempY| ) {
    tempX =tempX* ratio;
    tempY =tempY* ratio;
  }
  player.x += tempX;
  player.y += tempY;
}
```

I can solve the friction (getting the length of the movement vector, reducing it by the friction, projecting it back with the same x:y ratio), however, I can't wrap my head around getting the maxSpeed done.

I tried a solution of not allowing the player to walk at all when above maxSpeed, but this violates point 4. Also, it had the nasty side-effect, that when you moved at MaxSpeed to the left, and started pressing down, the movement direction didn't, or barely changed.

Then I started thinking about numerous products, differences and other stuff with the vectors, but I mostly couldn't follow it anymore or ran into early problems.

So in conclusion, could someone explain a system which fulfills all the points above, or point to an article which explains how a system like this could be implemented? Don't worry about suggesting something complex, I can grasp even difficult concepts given some time.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not letting you think about this for more than a day, but I managed to solve it, and it ain't two lines of code. (Though still thanks for everyone for the ideas)

Because I'm lazy and tired, I won't change it to pseudocode, except the following two methods:

```
updateGame(){
  player.walk();
  player.move();
}
player.move(){
  player.x += player.speedX
  player.y += player.speedY
}
```

And the code (java):

```
public void walk() {
    float tempX = 0;
    float tempY = 0;
    float accelX;
    float accelY;
    float nextSpeedX;
    float nextSpeedY;
    float nextSpeed;
    float speed;
    tempX += walkLeft ? -1 : 0;
    tempX += walkRight ? 1 : 0;
    tempY += walkUp ? -1 : 0;
    tempY += walkDown ? 1 : 0;

    if (Math.abs(tempX) == Math.abs(tempY)) {
        tempX = (float) tempX * rat;
        tempY = (float) tempY * rat;
    }

    accelX = tempX * (float) runSpeed;
    accelY = tempY * (float) runSpeed;
    speed = (float) Math.sqrt(speedX * speedX + speedY * speedY);
    nextSpeedX = speedX + accelX;
    nextSpeedY = speedY + accelY;
    nextSpeed = (float) Math.sqrt(nextSpeedX * nextSpeedX + nextSpeedY * nextSpeedY);

    if (nextSpeed > maxSpeed) { //can't accelerate by running
        if (nextSpeed > speed) {  //wants to accelerate
            if (speed > maxSpeed) {  //the current speed is larger than maximum.
                float diff = (float)(speed / nextSpeed);
                float greenX = nextSpeedX*diff;
                float greenY = nextSpeedY*diff;
                accelX = greenX-speedX;
                accelY = greenY-speedY;
            } else { //speed <= maxspeed
                float diff = (float)(maxSpeed / nextSpeed);
                float greenX = nextSpeedX*diff;
                float greenY = nextSpeedY*diff;
                accelX = greenX-speedX;
                accelY = greenY-speedY;
            }
        } else { //wants to slow! allow it!
            //acceleration doesn't need to be changed
        }
    } else { //no problem, allow it!
        //acceleration doesn't need to be changed
    }
    speedX += accelX;
    speedY += accelY;
}
```

Could be shorter, could be a bit more optimised, but it works. I hope this'll help anyone who stumbles upon this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the bottom:

```
 If (|tempX|>maxSpeed)
   tempX=maxSpeed*sign(tempX);

 If (|tempY|>maxSpeed)
   tempY=maxSpeed*sign(tempX);
```

Where
     int sign(x)
     {
         if x<0
          return -1;
     }

Comment: But if you walk eg. down+left, your speed in that diagonal direction will be sqrt(2*maxspeed*maxspeed) = 1.41. This is somewhat relevant to point 2, I could've written that cleaner.

Comment: @Szoltomi: Something like `If (|tempX, tempY| > maxSpeed) { tempX = sign(tempX)*maxSpeed*ratio; tempY=sign(tempY)*maxSpeed*ratio; }` would work for that, methinks.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's faster to code it in than error-check the theory. I'll let you know about the result soon.

Comment: What does sign(x) return when (x>=0) ?

Also, bugs: by player launched away with astronomical speeds. I also have other variables there I have to incorporate, so it's not super simple code inserting :P

Also: My dinamic world generator is astronomically fast

Comment: @Szoltomi probably 1, I guess the code should be:
int sign(x) { return x < 0 ? -1 : 1; }

Comment: @Edison: Yeah, I was just using `sign(x)` to indicate that the sign of tempX/tempY needed to be taken into account.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't implement your solution to work. Could you explain your line of thought perhaps? On the other I made a different solution which seemed to work. Made the big, explanatory self-answer, but decided to do a final test before posting. And saw that it violates the second part of Part 3. AAARGH. *tears hair out*. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest associating a specific velocity with the player in addition to position, and only checking that velocity against maxSpeed when arrow keys are pressed.

If the velocity DOES exceed maxSpeed, but the arrow keys from the opposite side are being pressed, then you'd keep the current velocity above maxSpeed and simply apply the negative acceleration.

Comment: The pseudocode is heavily simplified, I indeed have a separate speedX and Y variable, but edited it out. With your suggestion however I run into the problem I already written: If you move eg. left, and start holding left+down, you won't accelerate.

Comment: @Szoltomi: In such a case, you should decelerate the leftwards motion as the downwards motion accelerates. This fits in nicely with your second condition.